# Login with ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is my html

```
 <div id="stylized" class="myform">
        <form action="index.php" method="post" class="formPadd">
            <div align="right">
            <fieldset class="FloatLeft">

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="FloatRight" style="padding-right:14px;">
                <div style="height:40px; line-height:30px; text-align:center;">
                    <label>Username:</label><br>
                    <input class="inputbox" type="text" style="text-align:center; padding-right:14px;" name="uname" value maxlength="50">
                </div><br><br>
                <div style="height:30px; line-height:30px; text-align:center;">
                    <label align="center">Password:</label>
                    <input class="inputbox" type="password" name="pass" style="text-align:center; padding-right:14px;" value maxlength="50"><br><br>
                </div><br>                      
                <div>

                <button id="login" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
                    <span class="ui-button-text">Login</span>
                </button> 
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and heres my php

```
<?PHP
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();   

    if($_POST)
        {
            $un = $g->clean($_POST["username"]);
            $pw = $g->clean($_POST["password"]);
            $g->login($un, $pw);
        }

$g->close();
```

?>

and here's my db.classes

```
ublic function login($un, $pw)
    {
        $result = mysql_query("select username, password from admin where username='$un' and password='$pw'");

        $data = $this->getResults($result);
        $uName = $data["username"];
        $password = $data["password"];

        if($uName === $un && $password === $pw)
        {
            echo ('Correct');
        }

        else
        {
            echo 'Incorrect username/password';
        }
    }
```

And here's my ajax request

```
$( "#login" ).button().click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var un = $("input[name=uname]").val();
    var pw = $("input[name=pass]").val();
    var dataString = 'username='+ un + '&password='+ pw;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processLogin.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
    if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location.replace('list.php');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
        }
    }
    });
  });
```

I have already checked if my sql staments if they are to blame but they are fine. I think my problem is somewhere in the ajax request but i can't seem to point it out.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem, do the right values arrive at your php script for example?

Comment: Yes, maybe the problem is the echo from my db.classes is not returning it to data in my ajax function

Answer (score 0):

You need to narrow down where the problem is exactly, but the first thing I would change, is the way you build your query string in javascript. I am not sure if a data string gets encoded correctly if you send it directly, so I would use jQuery to make sure it does (in case your password contains funny characters for example).

Apart from that you are not using the data sent back from your ajax request in your javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processLogin.php",
    data: $('form.formPadd').serialize(),
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ serialize your form
    success: function(data){
    //                ^^^^ get the data
      if (data === 'Correct') {
      //            ^^^^^^^ this is what you echo in php
        window.location.replace('list.php');
      } else {
        alert('Invalid Credentials');
      }
    }
});
```

You would also have to change the names of the form fields or the POST variables in php so that they match again.

As a side-note, if you are going to redirect to another page in javascript, there is not much point in using ajax in the first place.